# Is there a way to pass printf letter (%c, %d) as a function argument?

Tags: c, printf

Please consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printStrGeneric(void *, int, int);
void printNumGeneric(void *, int, int);

int main()
{

    int intArray[] = { 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85 };

    printNumGeneric(intArray, sizeof(intArray), sizeof(int));
    printStrGeneric(intArray, sizeof(intArray), sizeof(int));
    puts("");

    short shortArray[] = { 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74 };

    printNumGeneric(shortArray, sizeof(shortArray), sizeof(short));
    printStrGeneric(shortArray, sizeof(shortArray), sizeof(short));
    puts("");

    return 0;
}

void printStrGeneric(void *object, int size, int elem_size)
{
    char *p = (char *) object;
    while (p < (char *) object + size) {
        printf("%c\t", *p);
        p += elem_size;
    }
    puts("");
}

void printNumGeneric(void *object, int size, int elem_size)
{
    char *p = (char *) object;
    while (p < (char *) object + size) {
        printf("%d\t", *p);
        p += elem_size;
    }
    puts("");
}
```

– given that the functions `printStrGeneric` and `printNumGeneric` are almost identical (except for the `printf` letter), I wonder whether it is in any way possible to have just 1 function instead, and pass a `printf` letter (either `%c` or `%d`) to the function as an argument?

Comment: Yes.  The format specifier is just a string.  Pass it in as a parameter to the function

Comment: It is possible, but not recommended because using something other than a string literal for your format string can open up [security vulnerabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontrolled_format_string).

Comment: As long as the argument is coming from the programmer I don't see that it's any more a security hole than is printf to begin with. The real security issues with printf come from passing any user-obtained string as the format string.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir you can't even rely on yourself to enter valid data. Did you ever have "finger trouble" even when you thought you knew what you were doing? All user input must be checked and tested. Without that basic principle, code will be weak and fall over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read about the usage of:

1. va_args
2. The syntax of: format, ...

Th combination of the two allows you to pass a format to a function, and handle it as you wish.

This is a very simple explanation: https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx11b.html

Comment: This is overkill for a simple choice of two formats and requires considerable work for a novice, particularly if one is to avoid vulnerabilities. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47822866/298225) by [Saravana Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6162823/saravana-kumar) is a more suitable immediate solution. Additionally, it does not give an actual solution, just a reference to information to study to figure out a solution.

Comment: That doesn't really seem to address the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Passing the format specifier as an argument is one way to do it like @OldProgrammer but like @0x5453 pointed out, it could be a vulnerability.

Are you against passing a bool value as an extra parameter and using an if condition to control the printf function? So your code would look like this:

```
void printGeneric(void *object, int size, int elem_size, bool str)
{
    char *p = (char *) object;
    if(str){
        while (p < (char *) object + size) {
            printf("%c\t", *p);
            p += elem_size;
        }
    }else{
        while (p < (char *) object + size) {
            printf("%d\t", *p);
            p += elem_size;
        } 
    }
    puts("");
}
```

Comment: You could simplify: `char *fmt = str? "%c\t" : "%d\t";` and then use this pointer in `printf` and drop the `if`.